# Nested_attributes rails not found with two nested's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a problem, I am saving an object with 2 nested_attributes, but it is saving only the second nested_attributes, if I back and update the first nested_attributes, it saves correctly. An attribute has  `has_many` and another `has_one`, it is saving just one at a time.

ex:

```
class Author
   has_many :books
   has_one :address

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :books
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :address

end

Params:
author: {books_attributes: {"0" => {title: "Title Test", id: 1}}, address_attributes: {city: "São Paulo", id: 2}}
```

This example saving only the author's books

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you show how you are actually using the params to create/update the record?

Comment: How does your form look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same problem, I couldn't resolve with a good way. I don't know why, but before save, it seems that the attributes of the address are being lost. I did this:

```
class Author    
     has_many :books    
     has_one :address
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :books   
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :address

     before_save :build_address_object
     after_save  :save_address_object!

     private

     def build_address_object
        @address = address
     end

     def save_address_object!
         return unless @address
         @address.author = self
         @address.save
     end
end
```

Note that the book validates the attributes of the address but when will save the address, it seems he loses parameters.